# Cron Wordpress Update four post every hour

Tags: wordpress, plugins, cron

I have function that update post content automatically based from custom field like this:

```
function update_content(){
$mycustomfield = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'customfield', true);

$post = array();
$post['ID'] = get_the_ID();
$post['post_content' ] = $mycustomfield ;
$post['post_title' ] = $mycustomfield ;

// Update the post into the database
wp_update_post( $post );
```

We update only custom field to make content. For now, we launch this function manually on save_post hook, but the articles are so many and we need now a cron to automate this function: process 4 posts every hour until all posts are completed, then start over.

How to make this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

WordPress actually has a built-in psuedo cron system called WP Cron. It doesn't function exactly like a proper server cron, but can perform a similar function in many cases. You can find documentation on it here:

[https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/#:~:text=WP%2DCron%20is%20how%20WordPress,post%2C%20utilize%20WP%2DCron.&text=WP%2DCron%20works%20by%20checking,what%20needs%20to%20be%20run](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/#:%7E:text=WP%2DCron%20is%20how%20WordPress,post%2C%20utilize%20WP%2DCron.&text=WP%2DCron%20works%20by%20checking,what%20needs%20to%20be%20run).

However thinking about your use case and looking at your function above, I'm wondering what the purpose of your cron is? It looks from that function like all you're doing is taking some content already in your database and putting it somewhere else. Why? Why not simply display your custom field in the correct spot? Or better yet, use the fields as intended?

Even if that is necessary - maybe I don't understand fully from the example above - I think your initial inclination to run this on save_post is much more correct. Unless there's some information external to your site that's changing, the only time these values will change is when you save the post. So what is the purpose of running it on a schedule?